# Jquery send value select on change

Tags: jquery, onchange

I try on change send value of select in load function of jquery , i use this

```
<script>
var value_sel_cat = jQuery('#cat_post').val();
</script>

<?php
print "<select name='anunpost[select_cat_post]' onchange=\"jQuery('#subcats').show(1000).load('index_subcats.php?id='+value_sel_cat)\" class='web_post_input_text' id='cat_post'>";

print "<option value='one'>1</option>";
print "<option value='two'>2</option>";

print "</select>";
?>
```

Here load the file i call from script with the index_subcats.php?id , in the id i want in each onchange the value of select :

```
<div id="subcats">Show hre the id in each onchange of select</div>
```

But all time tell me undefinied

Thabk´s , Regards

Comment: value_sel_cat will not have the updated value onchange.

Comment: I want send the value in load('index_subcats.php?id='+value_sel_cat)

Answer (score 0):

Just try `this.value`

```
print "<select name='anunpost[select_cat_post]' onchange=\"jQuery('#subcats').show(1000).load('index_subcats.php?id='+this.value)\" class='web_post_input_text' id='cat_post'>";
```

Comment: maybe this.options[this.selectedIndex].value instead of this.value?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>    
jQuery('#cat_post').live('change', function(){
   var value_sel_cat = jQuery('#cat_post').val();
   jQuery('#subcats').show(1000).load('index_subcats.php?id='+value_sel_cat)
});

</script>

 <?php
print "<select name='anunpost[select_cat_post]' class='web_post_input_text' id='cat_post'>";

print "<option value='one'>1</option>";
print "<option value='two'>2</option>";

print "</select>";
?>
```